# DNA to Binary Distance Computation

Tags: dna, bioinformatics

If I represent DNA as binary values, what is the best way of computing distance between them.

So :
A = 00,
T = 11,
G = 01 and
C = 10

Hamming Distance between ATGC and TAAC is 3, however their binary representations give a different answer:

Hamming Distance of 00110110 and 11000010 = 5.

Whats the best way of distance computation if the DNA bases are represented in this way?

Comment: It is a question of theoretical computer science, not biology. I am voting to close. You should give it a try on [cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Agree with @Remi.b. But before you leave us, "Why would you want to do that?" as IT Support used to say.

Comment: Ask this question on StackOverflow not cstheory

Comment: I found a solution, I'll answer it when you ask it again on StackOverflow

Comment: This is a relevant question for biology.se, I think. "what is the best way of computing ..." phrase in the question is misleading, however. The question is not about how to perform a computation, but rather how to represent some biological entity formally, in a biologically meaningful way. This is a question about theoretical biology, not about cs.

Comment: I encountered this problem when studying M.A.Nowak's book called Evolutionary Dynamics. There, the author introduces the concept of a sequence space, where he attributes "imagination" of it to John Maynard Smith.
Nowak's discussion is very superficial and does not include your question, and I don't have an answer to it, either.
But i think I can make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: A sequence space is a L-dimensional space for sequences (of DNA or whatever) of length L. Each sequence is a point in that space, and position of the point is determined such that, value of each position within sequence determines the coordinate of the corresponding dimension in the sequence space. Author suggests then the Hamming distance of sequences within this sequence space as a metric for similarity between sequences.

Comment: These definitions make perfect sense, when the sequences have binary elements. And also any sequence can be represented by a corresponding binary sequence, says the author, implying that the rest is straight forward, if we want to extend the definitions to any biological sequence.
But this is not a straight forward task, as the example in the question demonstrates.

Comment: Each coordinate, or position, in the sequence will be represented by 2 bits. But some of the bases differ in one of their bits (A and G for example), whereas some of them (A and T) differ in both of their bits. Of course plenty of speculations can be done about how to do it conveniently, but there is no obvious way, as far as I can see. A good answer could provide some examples from the evolutionary dynamics literature for example, about how it is done.

Comment: A last note, this more of a evolutionary dynamics / theoretical biology question, than a bioinformatics question. It is relevant, when a formal representation of biological sequences (mostly for simulation purposes) is needed. For more practical purposes, about calculating distance between actual sequences, Jack Aidley's answer provides some good foundation.

Comment: Thanks for telling me why you want to know. I imagine that comparing two alphabetic strings is not the same as comparing two binary strings even though you have 'converted' one to another. Which should one use for evolutionary comparison? No idea! To answer that I'd need to understand the Hanning distance to decide whether or not it is applicable to the problem. So I still think you need a computing scientist with some molecular genetics to discuss this with.

Comment: I didn't ask the question by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to choose a distance that represents what you want it to rather than necessarily relying on the Hamming distance.

If you simply want base-by-base difference then calculate that ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154745/efficient-way-to-or-adjacent-bits-in-64-bit-integer) may help) but you may also want a difference that depends on the likelyhood of mutating between different bases in which case you want to define a function that translates the mutation into a score for each transfer, i.e. you might want to score a deamination from 5-methylcytosine to thymine as the most likely occurrence. Expressing the relative likelyhoods of different mutations is not an easy problem but there are a number of widely used [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Models_of_DNA_evolution).

The important thing is to ensure you represent the underlying biology not ensure that you have the fastest implementation. Decide on this first, then on the algorithm that gives you the best speed (also, deciding on that algorithm is on-topic for Stack Overflow not this Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 0):

This encoding doesn't make sense as nucleotides are not in [the Hamming space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance#Properties). Hamming distance between every two nucleotides is constantly 1, but in binary encoding, it varies from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am reluctant to answer with code, but it seems that the community decided that was an appropriate question for Biology.SE. So here is my solution.

The idea is to "compress" the two bit that represent each nucleotide, such that each nucleotide will contribute 0 or 1 (not more) to the distance.

You could use binary operations to do something like this (in Java, but you can apply the logic in any language):

```
int seq1 = 54, seq2 = 194;//ATGC and TAAC
int evenBit = 0xAAAAAAAA, oddBit = 0x55555555;

int pseudoDist = seq1 ^ seq2; //Integer.bitCount(pseudoDist) is 5
int dist = ( (pseudoDist&evenBit)>>1 ) | (pseudoDist&oddBit);
int finalDist = Integer.bitCount(dist);//output 3 not five
```

The idea is to get the total number of bits that are different with:

```
seq1 ^ seq2
```

But you can't just count the bits yet, because you will get the hamming distance instead, so you have to compress all the bits that correspond to the same nucleotide to the same bit using: `(pseudoDist&0xAAAAAAAA>>1)` and `pseudoDist&0x55555555`. The first one keeps the bits on even positions and the second the ones on odd positions.

Now you use `evenBits | oddBits`, and you can count the bits.

Comment: The original question conflates mathematical operations with the edit distance between two strings. A hamming distance is a measure of the number of changes you have to make to convert one string into another string. Converting the the alphabet into binary digits and then adding or subtracting the numbers is not going to tell you how many edits were required.

Comment: @mdperry The fact that you don't understand it, does not invalidate it... You say it's impossible, but have you looked at my answer, have you tested it? Look it says that the hamming distance between `ATGC` and `TAAC` is 3, which is the right answer.

Comment: If your approach and solution is correct then it should be straightforward to apply your code to the examples on this page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance.

Comment: @mdperry this is not meant for any string, the fact that there are only four states possible allows you simplify it into 3 lines of code, that works for this particular problem

Comment: Actually, I now agree with you: my comment is incorrect, my apologies.